# How to call file name in this Python Socket?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I am working on a Python Socket-based file transfer script. The server can have 10 clients connected to it, all sending it files. The problem is, it only sends a file named 'libroR.pdf', if possible, I'd like the user to be able to specify the name and location of a custom file to send to the server. If it's possible, I would also like to be able to specify a custom host name for the client to connect to.

Server:

```
import socket
import sys

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("localhost",9999))
s.listen(10) # Acepta hasta 10 conexiones entrantes.

while True:
    sc, address = s.accept()

    print address
    i=1
    f = open('file_'+ str(i)+".pdf",'wb') #open in binary
    i=i+1
    while (True):       
    # recibimos y escribimos en el fichero
        l = sc.recv(1024)
        while (l):
                f.write(l)
                l = sc.recv(1024)
    f.close()


    sc.close()

s.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket
import sys

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("localhost",9999))
f=open ("libroR.pdf", "rb") 
l = f.read(1024)
while (l):
    s.send(l)
    l = f.read(1024)
s.close()
```

Thanks, Sean. :)

Comment: Can you fix the indentation? It looks like your while loops got flattened.

Comment: Yea, I see that. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import socket
import sys
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((raw_input("Enter a host name"),9999))
f = open(raw_input("Enter the file to send to the server: "), "rb") # On this line, you were getting a file allways named libroR.pdf, but the user can input the file now
l = f.read(1024)
while (l):
    s.send(l)
    l = f.read(1024)
s.close()
```

Comment: I think you misread the code. The client is not trying to receive from the socket. It is reading from the file and sending it to the socket.

Comment: I know. I was in the process of changing it while u sent this comment. Sorry.

Comment: @Tommy3244, I like :) Looking at that, wouldn't that mean the server would have to be slightly modified as well? :3

Comment: Also, I just tested it. It transfers the file perfectly, but it makes a empty file called 'file_1.pdf' THEN if your transferring a PDF file, waits for something to be sent to it and write the data to that file. Wondering how to make it save it as the same name and extension as it was entered into the server as.. any ideas? Thanks:)